# Store process output in array

Tags: c#, .net

I initiated an empty array - line.

```
 string[] line = new string[] { };
```

I want to store every line that would be outputed in a cmd processing with the while loop below. This seems to work easily if I store the values in a string variable.

As shown below:

```
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to store the values as separate elements in the array. I've tried:

```
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    for(a in line)
    {
        a = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But its not working.

This is probably a very basic question. But I'm still learning C#.

Comment: Use a List rather than an array.  Arrays are defined with fixed length, where a List can be added to and modified -> https://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: You should use a [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few solutions. One would be to use `List<string>` instead of `string[]`:

```
List<string> line = new List<string>();
```

And than add lines next way:

```
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    line.Add(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An array works on the basis of indexing. So if you want to use an array you need to specify how long it has to be or in other words how many items it can contain:

```
// this array can store 100 items
string[] line = new string[100];
```

To access a certain position you need to use the `[ ]` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index-operator) and to move forward in the array you need an indexing variable of type `int` that you can increment each iteration

```
int indexer = 0;

while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    line[indexer] = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    indexer ++; // increment
}
```

This way you need to know in advance how many items you want to deposit in your array.

Another way would be to use a flexible collection like [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) which can dynamically grow. Sidenote: The indexing works with the same `[ ]` operator, but the adding of items works via the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method

If you want to know more have look at this [overview of possible collection types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections)

Comment: Was currently writing update about how to solve it with Array. Your answer is very good, up-voted.

Comment: @Alex thanx, I though if you already posted a good solution I might explain the detailed working of OP's approach ;)